# Fire events in a web-component

Tags: javascript, events, web-component

I am trying to raise events out of a webcomponent, but it does.

```
<my-component id="xyz" bez="hallo" hello="myScript()"></my-component>
<script>
    xyz.addEventListener("hello", function(event) {
        console.log(event.detail.name);
    });
</script>
```

Neither the html-tag "hello" does raise the event, nor the event-listener does.

The web component looks like this:

```
var button=document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML=cap;
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log("click");
        
    button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("hello", {
        detail: { name: "John" }
    }));
});
    
shadow.appendChild(button);
```

Can anyone help me please to find the mistake?
Thanks a lot.

Code-Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/b43uqsLp/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem occurs because of the [**Shadow DOM**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM) (try to inspect your component and you will see what I mean):
[image]

Good news, it's really simple to fix - just propagate the event across the shadow DOM into the regular DOM via `composed: true` property in your CustomEvent's options:

```
button.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("hello", {
    detail: { name: "John" },
    composed: true // Like this
}));
```

Here is [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/m08xbz54/).

Comment: but how to fireEvent inline-hello?

Answer (score 5):

There is some information missing in the other answer

- the button `click` listener is **inside** shadowDOM, so `composed` has no use
- default listeners like `click` are **not** stopped by shadowDOM
- **!!!** CustomEvents require **both** `composed:true` and `bubbles:true` to escape Custom Elements with 'open' shadowDOM.
- do not attach listeners in the `connectedCallback` unless you are 100% certain that is what you want; the `connectedCallback` runs again when DOM elements are moved in the document
- `super()` returns **and** sets the 'this', and `attachShadow()` returns **and** sets the `this.shadowRoot` reference, no need to use your own variables.
  *run super first* means you can't access 'this' before it is created; but you can run any JS you want **before** the super() call

This JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/CustomElementsExamples/qody0u4n/

shows `composed` and `bubbles` behaviour, with extra listeners on the `document`

```js
  document.addEventListener("click", (evt) => log(evt, 'document'));
  document.addEventListener("MyEvent", (evt) => log(evt, 'document'));
```

```html
<my-component id=ONE></my-component>
<my-component id=TWO composed>
    <my-component id=INSIDETWO composed></my-component>
</my-component>
<my-component id=THREE composed bubbles>
    <my-component id=INSIDETHREE composed bubbles></my-component>
</my-component>
```

**notes**

- none of the MyEvents are caught by element ONE or the document
- The document only receives the `CustomEvent("MyEvent")` when both `composed` and `bubbles` are set
- The `composed` event does **not stop** at the shadowRoot boundary! It is halted at the **Custom Element boundary**. In the JSfiddle there are additional `DOMlisteners` on `my-component` to demonstrate this.

[image]

---

Also see: https://pm.dartus.fr/blog/a-complete-guide-on-shadow-dom-and-event-propagation/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation

Comment: Everytime I am reading an answer about web components, @Danny '365CSI' Engelman has answered it, thank you!

Comment: And before me Supersharp and Intervalia provided answers for many years